# How to get an async error handler on a observable subscribe to resolve and fully execute in Jest

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-test

I currently have a service that I want to test using jest and angular testing tools.

```
async login() {
  const credentials = this.loginForm.value;

  const loadingSpinner = await this.loadingCtrl.create();
  loadingSpinner.present();

  this.authService.login(credentials.email, credentials.password).subscribe(
  data => {
    loadingSpinner.dismiss();
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  },
  async error => {
    loadingSpinner.dismiss();
    const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'Failed to log in',
      position: 'top',
      cssClass: 'error-toast'
    });
    toast.present();
  }
 );
}
```

The code above makes use of the awaits in the error handler. When attempting to use the fakeAsync with tick or flushing all micro tasks, the toastCtrl.create does not fire. When I rewrite the code using the async test the toast.present does not fire but the create does. Below is the test and response.

```
    it('should make a call to login fire a toast if there is an error', async(() => {
      authService.login.mockReturnValue(throwError({}));
      component.login().then(() => {
        expect(loadingCtrl.create).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(loadingInstance.present).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(loadingInstance.dismiss).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(toastCtrl.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
          message: 'Failed to log in',
          position: 'top',
          cssClass: 'error-toast'
        });
        expect(toastInstance.present).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
```

The result I get from jest is

```
 AuthComponent › controller › functions › login › should make a call to login fire a toast if there is an error

Uncaught (in promise): Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

  132 |               cssClass: 'error-toast'
  133 |             });
> 134 |             expect(toastInstance.present).toHaveBeenCalled();
      |                                           ^
  135 |           });
  136 |         }));
  137 |       });
```

The question I have is simple, why is the awaits not fully resolving in the tests. 
If you use setTimeout with 1000ms and the done callback instead of the async wrapper this does work.

Comment: Does your error block inside `login()` executes?

Comment: As evidence by the response it does indeed.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

`toast.present()` is still [queued in `PromiseJobs`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) and hasn't run by the time the `expect` asserts and fails.

### Solution

Let any callbacks queued in `PromiseJobs` run before asserting:

```js
it('should make a call to login fire a toast if there is an error', async () => {
  authService.login.mockReturnValue(throwError({}));
  await component.login();   // await login
  expect(loadingCtrl.create).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(loadingInstance.present).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(loadingInstance.dismiss).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(toastCtrl.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    message: 'Failed to log in',
    position: 'top',
    cssClass: 'error-toast'
  });
  await Promise.resolve();   // allow pending callbacks in PromiseJobs to run
  expect(toastInstance.present).toHaveBeenCalled();   // SUCCESS
});
```

### Details

The callbacks passed to `subscribe` aren't part of `component.login` so the callbacks may or may not have run when the `Promise` returned from `component.login` resolves and the test continues.

In this case the `error` callback has been called and has made it to the `create` call but the rest of the callback hasn't run yet by the time `expect(toastInstance.present).toHaveBeenCalled();` runs and fails.

Ideally tests directly `await` any asynchronous code being tested but since this is not possible with an asynchronous callback an alternative is to `await` a resolved `Promise` which essentially queues the rest of the test at the end of `PromiseJobs` behind any pending callbacks, giving the other callbacks a chance to run before continuing the test.

**Note:** you may have noticed that `Jest` was completely exiting with an unhandled exception instead of just reporting that the test failed.  The way the test is written in the question the `Promise` returned from `component.login().then()` is neither returned nor `await`-ed so the test completes and the failed `expect` in the `then` callback ends up happening outside the test causing `Jest` to exit.  The easiest way to resolve this (implemented in the solution above) is to remove the `then` callback and simply `await` the `Promise` returned from `component.login` before beginning the `expect` assertions.

Comment: Disclaimer: the code in the answer is untested since I don't have access to the full codebase, let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Seems legit makes sense and I'll try after this amazing weekend.